# How to use LoadManager and AsyncTaskLoader with different activities?

Tags: android, httprequest, background-task, asynctaskloader

I am fairly new to android development and have been searching for the solution for the past few days.

I have a few activities in my app and each activities has to send request to web server(for example  "login" activity send Http request "GET" , "Update" activity send Http request "POST") . That means , every activity has to perform background operations.

Can I manage in LoadInBackground in AsyncTaskLoader my backgroundtasks from my activites? , if every activities contains LoadManager? Or I sould use something else?

Could anyone can give me some hints , which way is the best to perfom multi Background tasks ?

Comment: use retrofit for network operations http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I'm new in Android and I wanted to do it without external libraly , because I have to learn basic things about backgroundTask. Could you recommend me , with way I should use as a beginner . Should I start with retrofit ?

Comment: You can start with this https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853